# Intuitions for constructing fibrant/cofibrant objects for a homotopy theory.

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

I have heard that doing homotopy theory in a category requires only weak equivalences since we can formally localise the category. The class of fibrations and cofibrations are auxiliary constructs that allow us to do computations in the homotopy category by the construction of fibrant-cofibrant replacement procedures.

Suppose I have been given a particular category and a class of morphisms as weak equivalences, how do I guess/construct/"sense" a good definition of fibrant or cofibrant objects? In other words, are there some basic intuitions on how to endow a category with a model structure?

Comment: It depends on the kind of objects you work with. In the situations I am familiar with cofibrant objects are like free algebras (i.e. no extra relations between generators) while fibrant objects are like complete algebras (i.e. every equation that “should” have a solution does have a solution).